# MVC 5, HttpGet works, HttpPost does not work, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making some custom methods in an MVC 5/Web Api. I try to make a custom GET method as follows:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("TrainItemCheckIfWorks")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string TrainItemCheckIfWorks()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Which works beautifully. I do the same thing with HttpPost, as follows:

```
[Route("CheckPost")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public double[] GetPostItem()
    {
        return new double[] {1, 2, 3};
    }
```

The HttpPost fails but I do not get a specfic error. I just get Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /TrainItemModels/CheckPost

THis is very frustrating and I have been spending all weekend trying to figure out why I am getting this error. Any help will greatly help

Comment: Is `TrainItemModels` the name of your controller?  Make sure to use POST request method (your browser bar address can't do that) in something like Postman or if you're using jQuery to set the correct JSON property.

Comment: How are you testing if your post call works? Postman? Ensure you're actually creating a Post request

Comment: Can you check post to url `/CheckPost` works instead of `/TrainItemModels/CheckPost` ? Unless `TrainItemModels` is the name of your applciation(virtual directory), your url is wrong with respect to your route specified.

Comment: I will try that now! No it didn't work I get the exact same error very frustrating.

Comment: @user3363022, This question is incomplete. provide a [mcve] of the problem so that the issue can be reproduced and a possible solution can be derived. The information provided will not allow other to effectively assist you as there is too much left to guess.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get it to work? I have the exact same problem. All my HttpGet functions in my MVC controller work, but all HttpPost returns 404.

Comment: I actually downloaded and used postman to make POST calls work. It was free.